I want to use the onclick hook in the iframe React.js
"I want to use the onclick hook in the iframe since it's not allowed in the iframe tag. However, using a div to achieve this disables video playback. Is it possible to do this with an iframe, or is it necessary to change the tag?"
 <iframe
      className="video-frame"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S4tTwNyzeyI"
      title="YouTube video player"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowFullScreen
      id="videoIframe"
      onClick={() => {
        setVideoClicked(true);
        handleVideoClick();
        console.log('videoClicked:', handleVideoClick);
      }}
    ></iframe>

